# Fill python dictionary in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I need fill empty dictionary in loop, but my script give me error. How can I do that operation? Thanks

Script:

```
import numpy as np

name = np.asarray(["John", "Peter", "Jan", "Paul"])
score = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4])

apdict = {"Name": "null", "Score": "null"}

for name in name:
    for score in score:
        apdict["Name"][name] = name[name]
        apdict["Score"][score] = score[score]
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-814-25938bb38ac2>", line 8, in <module>
    apdict["Name"][name] = name[name]

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

[image]

Possible outputs:

```
#possible output 1:
apdict = {["Name": "John", "Score": "1"], ["Name": "Peter", "Score": "3"]}

#possible output2:
apdict = {["Name": "John", "Score": "1", "3", "4"], ["Name": "Paul", "Score": "1"]}
```

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: My question is updated, I added outputs.

Comment: I think your output should better be represented as "list of dictionary" instead of something looks invalid Python syntax ([...] enclosing something like a dict but a dict should be enclosed in `{...}` rather than `[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a dict with elements in `name` as keys and elements in `score` as values, based on the 2 numpy arrays, you can do it as follows:

```
apdict = dict(zip(name, score))


print(apdict)

{'John': 1, 'Peter': 2, 'Jan': 3, 'Paul': 4}
```

### Edit

Based on your newly added possible output, I think it would better be "*list of dictionary*" instead of something looks like **set** of something (since {...} immediately encloses lists) that looks like **lists** (since [...] encloses something) but those something enclosed in list looks more like a dictionary rather than legitimate list items.  The valid format of "*list of dictionary*"  should look like below:

```
[{'Name': 'John', 'Score': 1},
 {'Name': 'Peter', 'Score': 2},
 {'Name': 'Jan', 'Score': 3},
 {'Name': 'Paul', 'Score': 4}]
```

In this case, you can achieve it as follows:

```
apdict = [{'Name': k, 'Score': v} for k, v in zip(name, score)]


print(apdict)

[{'Name': 'John', 'Score': 1},
 {'Name': 'Peter', 'Score': 2},
 {'Name': 'Jan', 'Score': 3},
 {'Name': 'Paul', 'Score': 4}]
```

Alternatively, you can also use Pandas (as you tagged <kbd>pandas</kbd> in the question), as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

apdict = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name, 'Score': score}).to_dict('records')


print(apdict)

[{'Name': 'John', 'Score': 1},
 {'Name': 'Peter', 'Score': 2},
 {'Name': 'Jan', 'Score': 3},
 {'Name': 'Paul', 'Score': 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the element with an index of string instead of an integer:

```
apdict["Name"][name] = name[name]
```

`name` needs to be an integer.